# VMWare PowerShell script Get-VM where tag not like

Tags: powershell, vmware

I am trying to run a VMWare powershell script where I grab all the VM's besides the ones with the tag "NO_SNAPSHOT"

To get the list of VM's I run this to remove the ones with the tag "NO_SNAPSHOT"

```
$VMs = Get-VM| Where-Object { $_.tag -notlike '*NO_SNAPSHOT*'}
```

However it doesn't work, it still lists all the VM's

Answer (score 1):

Objects returned by `Get-VM` do not have a property called 'Tag'. Check out [Get-TagAssignment](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-TagAssignment.html).

edit - so you could do

```
$TAs = Get-TagAssignment | where {$_.tag.name -like "*no_snapshot*"}
$VMs = get-vm | where { $TAs.entity.name -notcontains $_.name }
```

Or if you have PowerCLI [v5.8r1](http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2014/11/feature-powercli-5-8-r1-filtering-tags.html#more-1918) you could do

```
$noSnap = get-vm -tag *no_snapshot*
$vms = get-vm | where {$noSnap.name -notcontains $_.name}
```

Comment: How would I do want I want though?